# Science fiction book about everyone vanishing except two guys and a young boy

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a book that I was only about 5 chapters into. I started reading it a few years ago and have been unable to find it again since. It is not *The Vanished*, *Left Behind*, or *Gone* series.

1. It was around 800-1000 pages.
2. I was reading it on scribd but it IS a published book.
3. I think it is actually the first book in a series.
4. I am fairly sure it was an adult book, not YA.
5. The story had 3 perspectives/storylines, at least as far as I had read. I might not have them in the correct order.
6. One perspective had a boy who was abused by his stepdad or dad. He woke up in his house and it was empty, no parents. He went outside and it was basically abandoned and no one was out. His friend's dad, a coach, had a classic car. I think it was red. But the boy had to go to the house and find the keys to the car so he could drive out of town (I think just to explore or try to find answers as to why people were gone). He might have had psychic or some type of ability, because even though he could not find the keys, his mind showed him where they were. The boy was unable to reach the pedals, so he had to create some blocks/pedal extensions. While on the freeway, he crashed. Almost as if there was a monster or something caused it. Then the next perspective starts.
7. The second guy woke up handcuffed in the back of a police car. When he woke up, he knew he had to break out, so he did and tried to hide. He ran into a home and was afraid the homeowners would catch him, but since everyone had vanished or were gone, he was in an empty house. Then the next perspective starts.
8. The third guy had a wife and maybe a baby. He woke up in his apartment and things were dark. He searched for his family but could not find them. He went into the apartment hallway and realized everyone was gone. He looked out a window and saw the area was empty, but saw something. I can't remember if it was a small group of people or just something that caught the guy's eye. He went outside and saw nothing, just the empty streets. He looked back at his apartment and saw something in the sky.
9. I was so early in the book, but there may have been a female character, but I am not sure.
10. I think one of the guys was going to find/come across the boy who had wrecked the car on the freeway.
11. I think it was written by a male author.
12. I want to say it was written between 2000-2010.

Answer (score 21):

Possibly 'Yesterday's Gone' by Sean Platt [Goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12814430-yesterday-s-gone)

Description from the site:

> They thought they were alone. They were wrong.
>
> On October 15th, humanity went missing.
>
> A handful of scattered survivors wake to find the world empty of friends, family, and neighbors.
>
> Among them, a child searches for his family. A special agent turned enemy of the state survives a fiery plane crash with no way to reach his daughter. A serial killer discovers he’s no longer at the top of the food chain.

### It was around 800-1000 pages.

461 apparently so a little shorter

### I was reading it on scribd but it IS a published book.

Kindle and paperback available

### I think it is actually the first book in a series.

One of six

### I am fairly sure it was an adult book, not YA.

Warning 'for mature audiences'

### The story had 3 perspectives/storylines, at least as far as I had read. I might not have them in the correct order.

Blurb describes three unique characters

### One perspective had a boy who was abused by his stepdad or dad.

Reviews mention an abusive parent, and a child is one of the characters.

### The second guy woke up handcuffed in the back of a police car.

Again, blurb mentions a killer - plausible to be in handcuffs?

### The third guy had a wife and maybe a baby.

Third character is trying to reach his daughter, so some family about.

### I think it was written by a male author.

Yep

### I want to say it was written between 2000-2010.

2011

Found with search 'handcuffs stepfather vanished site:goodreads.com'

Comment: YES. That is it!

Comment: Happy to help! If you feel the answer is complete, please consider marking it as accepted with the check mark to the side.

Comment: I'm always amazed by how fast people come up with (right) answers to these questions, but I'm probably even more amazed by the search that led you there!

Comment: Couple of iterations of key words needed to get something plausible. Limiting to results from Goodreads can be helpful in identifying books.